# How to add request-response lifecycle hook in spring webflux

Tags: spring-webflux

I'd like to add some lifecycle hook on spring webflux to meature the whole request-response trip.

Question is: where to put start and where to put end.

What I guess is go with a WebFitler (first one to execute):

**start**: before WebFilterChain.filter

**end**: inject end logic into mono.doOnSuccessOrError

The problem is I'm not sure whether the doOnSucessOrError callback executed after HandlerResultHandler.

What I expect for "end":

The whole body send out. ( or in a chunked case, the last chunk send out.)

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Leon

Comment: Nice! I think this is pretty much close to my question. Thanks a lot!